# Where can I learn random matching models?

Tags: game-theory, contract-theory

The title says all. I need papers or textbooks that explain in detail (step by step, maybe showing some canonical results) how I can model random matching games. Does anyone have a reference?

Thank you.

Comment: That title does not say it all. Can you give a bit more indication of the kind of models you want to learn? There are very different models that one might describe as random matching models.

Answer (score 3):

If you have in mind infinite populations I'd suggest [Carlos Alós-Ferrer (1999) *Dynamical Systems with a Continuum of Randomly Matched Agents*, **Journal of Economic Theory** 86 (2), 245-267](https://doi.org/10.1006/jeth.1999.2522).

Comment: Add the cost of more mathematical machinery, one gets much more powerful results in the paper: Podczeck, Konrad, and Daniela Puzzello. "[Independent random matching](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00199-010-0584-4)." Economic Theory 50.1 (2012): 1-29.